# Как центрировать текст под блоком с данными времени?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

День бодрый, как можно выставить "дней / часов / минут / секунд" под нулями ровно, как в макете.
[image: Макет]

Я сделал это так:
HTML:

```
<div class="stock"><span class="stock_text"><b>До конца акции осталось</span>
            <p class="stock_time">00 : 00 : 00 : 00</p></b>
            <p class="stock_data">дней часов минут секунд</p>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.stock_time {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 55px;
    word-spacing: 10px;
}

.stock_data {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    word-spacing: 55px;
}
```

Как результат:
[image: Моё]

Comment: Можно это сделать, сделав выравнивание по центру. Покажите ваш HTML и CSS разметку, тогда можно будет дать более точный ответ

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, нажав кнопку "править" и добавьте эту информацию туда.

Comment: В вашем html-коде принцип неправильный. Вы сделали две горизонтальные строчки, а нужно сделать четыре вертикальные колонки и выровнять их с помощью flexbox например

Comment: Я не особо продвинутый в разметке, про flexbox знаю. А вот как сделать колонки я не знаю, если вы не про таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```css
  .times {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .times > div > div:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .times > div > div:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .times > div {
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="times">
  <div>
    <div>00</div>
    <div>дней</div>
  </div>
  <div> : </div>
  <div><div>00</div><div>часов</div></div>
  <div> : </div>
  <div><div>00</div><div>минут</div></div>
  <div> : </div>
  <div><div>00</div><div>секунд</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно Вот так:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #283D46;
}

.title {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.date>td {
  font-size: 86px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="7" class="title">До конца акции осталось</th>
      </tr>
      <thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="date">
            <td>00</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>00</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>00</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Дней</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Часов</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Минут</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Секунд</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```